# Variable Scope in Methods (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, scope

I've got a quick question about scope in methods.  I'm aware of local vs. global variable scope on the general level, but what happens when a variable is declared inside a method to an object?  **Can the variable in one method be accessible inside another method under the same object?**

Comment: Local variables are local to the function in which they were declared. Methods are just functions.

Comment: Are you looking for object properties maybe?

Comment: If the object is declared globally and you add a _property_ to it (not a _variable_), then yes, that property is accessible anywhere the object is.

Answer (score 0):

No. If a variable is declared in a method, its scope is that method. To be accessible in a object it must be declared in the object, outside of any one method.